# Calling and printing object inside object in swift 2

Tags: ios, swift2

I have  2 classes, I have cats object in the AnimalClass and I am parsing jSON and I want to initialize the cats name from the jSON

```
class AnimalClass: NSObject {

    var cats = [catClass]()
    ..... 
}
```

And

```
class catClass: NSObject {

var name : String = ""

init(data : NSDictionary)
{
    if let add = data["name"] as? String
    {
        self.name = add
    }
```

Here I am trying to initialize it in the ViewController.swift

```
    var animals = [AnimalClass]()
for(var i = 0; i < data_array.count; i++)
{
    if let add = data_array[i] as? NSDictionary
    {
      self.animals.append(AnimalClass(data: add)) // this works
      self.animals.cats.append(AnimalClass(data: add)) // this doesn't work
    }
}
```

My question is for this line `self.animals.cats.append(AnimalClass(data: add))` how can append to cats object which is in the AnimalClass.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to append `AnimalClass` to cats because cats is an array of `catClass` objects. You declared it like this:

```
var cats = [catClass]()
```

That's why the code below won't work.

```
self.animals.cats.append(AnimalClass(data: add))
```

So you should change it to:

```
  self.animals.cats.append(catClass(data: add))
```

Moreover, class names in Swift should start with capital letter and I recommend you rename `catClass` to `Cat` (also dropping the `Class` suffix)

Comment: Thanks, but how can I append cats object ? I need to append cats object over the AnimalClass

Comment: I tried but now it says : Value of type '[Animals]' has no memeber 'cats' . But there I have created cats object inside Animals class. I don't understand why it says that.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make use the init for your cat class.

change the line:

```
self.animals.cats.append(AnimalClass(data: add))
```

to:

```
self.animals.cats.append(CatClass(data: add))
```

Comment: Thanks, but now it says : Value of type '[Animals]' has no memeber 'cats'

Comment: What's the point of providing an answer which is a copy & paste of mine? You even capitalized the `catClass` as I suggested in my answer. And I truly appreciate the down vote for telling you how it looks like.

Comment: @Bearwithme - i had finished writing my answer then noticed you had written the same as its an obvious solution.

Comment: Interesting, you posted your answer 7 minutes after mine was posted.

Comment: yours was edited "13 mins ago", mine was "answered 12 mins ago" obviously an error like that could occur in a minute

Comment: @tmac99 notice the brackets around [Animals] that means it is of type "Array of Animals" thus it doesn't have a member "cats" i'm not exactly sure, why you have it in an array but you will need to subscript animals to append a cat to that instance of animal try this self.animals[0].cats.append(AnimalClass(data: add))